# ConfigureAwait(false) with UI controls?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, async-await

Is it OK to use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` for the following two code snippets?

**Case 1**

```
var ds = new BindingSource();
ds.DataSource = await CallAsync(); // .ConfigureAwait(false);
UIControl.DataSource = ds;
```

**Case 2**

```
UIControl.DataSource = new BindingSource
{
    DataSource = await CallAsync() // .ConfigureAwait(false)
};
```

Does the first one seem to have the problem of set UI control at the background thread? How about the second one?

Comment: Yes both cases have problem.

Comment: It's not clear why you are considering `ConfigureAwait(false)` in this, well, *context*. Is it about `CallAsync()` not being that much *async*? Are you using `Task.Run()` in the implementation of a not-so-much `async` method? Maybe it's just partially `async`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All access to controls should be done in the same thread which the control is created.

By calling [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait?view=netframework-4.7.2) you are asking not to attempt to marshal the continuation back to the original context captured. It means the code continue the execution in a different context than the UI thread which is invalid operation.

So, the answer is yes, both above cases have problem and will result in:

> InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Control Name' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Data binding cannot generate that exception, notorious problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you mean the cases which are mentioned in the question or some different cases? (I've already tested question cases and they throw exception.)