# To run or not run ConfigureAwait(false) with both services and activities with Xamarin Android ver 8, .net Standard

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, async-await, task-parallel-library

I came across articles below regarding when and where to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, but cannot get an answer.

> You Don’t Need ConfigureAwait(false), But Still Use It in Libraries,
>   and UI apps. (e.g. Xamarin, WinForms etc)

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954703/configureawaitfalse-with-ui-controls) says opposite answer

[Best practice to call ConfigureAwait for all server-side code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code)

[When correctly use Task.Run and when just async-await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013523/when-correctly-use-task-run-and-when-just-async-await)

My questions:

**Scenario 1**: The code below is running as background service.

My question: Is `ConfigureAwait(false)` required for whenever `await` is used like both A and B below:

```
    [Service(Name = "com.MainApplicationService", Label = "Main Application Service", Exported = false)]
    public class MainApplicationService : Android.App.Service
    {

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        [return: GeneratedEnum]
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            await InitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);   //line A

            Task.Run(async () => await InitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));   //line B

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }
    }
```

**Scenario 2**: 
The code below is running as UI thread as opposed to background service

Same question: Is `ConfigureAwait(false)` required for whenever await is used like both C and D below:

```
public class StartupActivity : Android.App.Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        await InitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);  //line C

        Task.Run(async () => await InitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));  //line D

        Finish();
    }
}
```

Xamarin Android ver 8, I think it is .net standard.

https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md

Comment: Are you missing `await` here:  `Task.Run(async () => await InitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));   //line B` ?

Comment: Are you missing `async` modifier on  `OnStartCommand` and `OnCreate` methods?

Comment: yes, that is another issue that I need to find out. Do you know the answer?

Comment: I've shared my thoughts on that. Regarding using async APIs from async or non-async `void` methods like in your case, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/22629951/1768303 and linked Q/As.

Comment: @noseratio Thanks for the link.

Comment: Double check: use discard like this `_ = WorkAsync();` to suppress warning, but it doesn't catch exception. To handle exception, I need to define an extension method like `Forget. ` on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864367/fire-and-forget-approach/22864616#22864616  ???

Comment: I've edited my answer to address your comments.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps an unpopular opinion, but these days I don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` even in libraries, see:

"[Revisiting `Task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410046/revisiting-task-configureawaitcontinueoncapturedcontext-false)"

IMO, *if* the code that consumes a `Task`-based API is concerned about the current synchronization context and how it might affect that API's behavior (deadlocks, redundant context switches, etc.), it can explicitly wrap the API invocation with `Task.Run` or use something like `TaskExt.WithNoContext` from the above link:

```cs
await Task.Run(() => InitAsync());
// or
await TaskExt.WithNoContext(() => InitAsync());
```

In most cases though, especially for UI apps (where there's a synchronization context, but threading scalability is not an issue), it's OK to leave it as is, without `Task.Run` or `ConfigureAwait`:

```
await InitAsync();
```

This would give you a chance to discover and investigate potential deadlocks, before trying to mitigate them with `ConfigureAwait(false)` or `Task.Run`.

So, it is not *always* a bad idea to continue on the same synchronization context, especially inside `async void` methods where unhandled exceptions are posted to the current synchronization context, see [TAP global exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22395161/1768303).

---

**Updated** to answer the questions in the comments:

> What is the difference between `await Task.Run(() => InitAsync());` and
>   `Task.Run(async () => await InitAsync());` and `await Task.Run(async () => await InitAsync());`

In this case (a simple `async` lambda to `Task.Run`) the difference would be just an extra overhead of async/await compiler-generated state machine, which you don't need. The task, returned by `InitAsync`, will get unwrapped by `Task.Run` automatically, either way. For more general cases, see "[Any difference between "await Task.Run(); return;" and "return Task.Run()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21033150/1768303)".

I'd use an `async` lambda here only if I needed to do something else after the completion of `InitAsync`, while still not having to worry about synchronization context, e.g.:

```
await Task.Run(async() => {
    await InitAsync();
    // we're on a pool thread without SynchronizationContext
    log("initialized");
});
```

> Double check: use discard like this `_ = WorkAsync();` to suppress
>   warning, but it doesn't catch exception. To handle exception, I need
>   to define an extension method like `Forget`. on
>   [Fire and Forget approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864367/fire-and-forget-approach/22864616#22864616)

Yes, that'd be my choice for fire-and-forget. However, I don't think your `InitAsync` is a true fire-and-forget in your case. Perhaps, it'd be better to keep track of it in the class instance: `_task = InitAsync()` and observe `_task` later.

Or, better yet, you could use an `async void` helper method inside `OnCreate` to observe the result/exceptions of `InvokeAsync`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    async void function invokeInitAsync()
    {
        try 
        {
            await InitAsync();
            Finish();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            // handle the failure to initialize
            await promptAndExitUponErrorAsync(e);
        }
    }

    invokeInitAsync();
}
```

It might be possible to make `OnCreate` itself `async void`, but then exceptions (if any) from `base.OnCreate()` wouldn't be getting synchronously propagated to the caller of your override, which may have other side effects. Thus, I'd use a helper `async void` method, which can be also local as above.

**Finally**, consider embracing asynchrony in your `ViewModel` layer, and then you woudn't have to worry about it in places like `OnCreate`. For more details, see: "[How to Unit test ViewModel with async initialization in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31289216/1768303)".

Comment: What is the difference between `await Task.Run(() => InitAsync());` and `Task.Run(async () => await InitAsync());` and `await Task.Run(async () => await InitAsync());`

Comment: @Pingpong, I've edited my answer to address your comments.

Comment: I forgot to ask: Do you mean ConfigureAwait(false) is NOT required for lines A, B, C and D?

Comment: @Pingpong, I agree with Stephen Cleary that it's never required, on your A/B/C/D lines either. It's often uses as an optimization to avoid redundant context switches (less relevant these days) and often mis-used as a remedy to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: Is a method with `async void` a bad practice or ok to use? Because I have an event handler that cannot have `async Task`.

Comment: @Pingpong there're use cases where `async void` can be appropriate, like fire-and-forget invocations, event handlers or notification-style `void` virtual overrides like your `OnCreate`. Otherwise, `async void` wouldn't be allowed by the C# compiler in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

> Is ConfigureAwait(false) required

`ConfigureAwait(false)` is never required, unless you're using it as part of a [direct blocking sync-over-async hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development), which is never recommended.

If you need to stay on the same context (e.g., you're accessing UI elements), then the question is moot: you *cannot* use `ConfigureAwait(false)` because your code must resume on the same context. This is the scenario for your ["opposite answer" link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954703/configureawaitfalse-with-ui-controls).

For libraries, the traditional approach is to recommend `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere, because library authors don't know how their libraries will be consumed. This was especially true because there were a few situations (primarily in ASP.NET) where sync-over-async hacks were required.

However, now that ASP.NET Core is async all the way (no longer requiring blocking hacks) and also doesn't have a context at all, the chances that a library will be used with sync-over-async is significantly reduced. So some libraries have started dropping `ConfigureAwait(false)` - most notably Entity Framework Core. Time will tell whether `ConfigureAwait(false)` will continue, or whether it will become a historical oddity.

For myself, I do use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in my libraries, which are commonly used on older platforms. But if you have a library that is only consumed by modern UI and Core apps, then it's not necessary.

Comment: Can you point out which section is about  sync-over-async? Even better Is it possible to provide a code example?  "modern UI and Core apps" is there a away to test it myelf.

Comment: @Pingpong: That article is about sync-over-async techniques, but you could start reading at "Vertical Partitions".

Comment: Do you mean `ConfigureAwait(false)` is NOT required for lines A, B, C and D?
Can you point out which section is about  sync-over-async? Even better Is it possible to provide a code example?  
"modern UI and Core apps" Is it possible to provide code to test if `ConfigureAwait(false)` is required or not?

Comment: @Pingpong: `ConfigureAwait(false)` is not required for any of those lines. Almost the entire article is about sync-over-async strategies. `ConfigureAwait(false)` is only *required* if the calling code blocks and there's a one-thread-at-a-time context. There isn't a way to check for this in code, or else everyone would just do that and "magically do the right thing".

Comment: I have a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59096962/2674222) and  I hope you can share or opinion it. Thanks Stephen!

Comment: Does  ConfigureAwait(false)  run on separate thread than main thread on UI applications? and we need to return back to UI thread if want to display result on the UI?

Comment: @batmaci: `ConfigureAwait(false)` controls where the code runs *after* the `await`. If you're on the UI thread before the `await` and you want to resume on the UI thread after the `await`, then you should *not* use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: @StephenCleary what if library has async implementations and client must execute those as sync (unfortunately because of DI on different platforms) , is it safe to use just ".Result" suffix. I went through your articles and you suggest to use configureawait false or Thread.run. I understand that it goes off the UI thread but can we not return back to UI thread. Is it a bad design?

Comment: @batmaci: My [brownfield async article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development) discusses several different approaches and the tradeoffs of each.